# How do I add Login fields and registration link to the header?

Tags: login, user-registration

I want to have a login username and password field in the header, and a registration link beside it. I want the registration link to go away once the user is logged in and the login fields to be replace with a logout link.

I have found these two snippets but they don't help me achieve what I want.

Comment: You said "snippets", but didn't show any...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wp_login_form(); // Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form
// or:
wp_loginout(); // Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) // Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in
    wp_register('', ''); // Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register
```

Comment: Thanks, however. that doesn't remove the login box after login, or provide a register link.

Comment: Straight from the Codex `wp_register()` functions description: "This tag displays either the _Site Admin_ link if the user is logged in or **Register** link if the user is not logged in." The `if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )` can be wrapped around any of those three functions - also around the `wp_login_form()` function. So everything you asked for is in those 5 lines of the answer including links to the Codex and the according description. - Btw: As mentioned above: Please provide your "snipplets" including an explanation how and where you placed them.